# Is it possible to remove the navigation bar button in in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using shortcuts to do those function. So can I remove these navigation bar button in VScode? 
It make my opened file's name out  of sight.

The navigation bar button, I mean, is on the right of the title bar.

I can't post an image now, because of low reputation. Hope you can understand my question.

Comment: you can post a link of the image

Comment: do you mean the `...` button? If so your screen is very small or your filename is very big, or you have  opened many times the same file name from other directories that are on a long relative path.